# Need to export one SQL Server table of 150GB into multiple pipe delimited flat files

Tags: sql, sql-server, export, bcp

Need to export one SQL Server table of 150GB size into multiple pipe delimited flat files

The table only has 2 columns, PK `uniqueidentifier not null` and `text null`

Been doing set rowcount BCP queryout where uniqueidentifier greater than but table is being updated and order of PK changes there is no ID.

Just looking for a way to quickly dump this large table so they can import to Oracle via SQL Loader

No we do not want to use SSIS for various reasons

Comment: Is the size because of the text column, or because the number of rows?

Comment: 700,000 rows, Unique ID is a GUID,  text is XML Data, limited SSIS experience and SSIS put brackets around GUID and BCP does not, I can export to multiple file with BCP pipe delimited doing where GUID > than  but GUID order changes and I need same script for  Test and PROD, I am afraid I may miss or duplicate a row doing it this way

Answer (score 0):

Given the number of rows is relatively manageable, I would recommend first writing your uniqueidentifiers to a temporary table and assign a row number column, using a select similar to below:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY uniqueidentifier ASC) AS RowNumber, uniqueidentifier 
FROM table
```

You can then join your temp table back to your actual data, and have a range of row numbers for which to filter on for you bcp batches.